# Passing pointer of pointers to function, returning both an int and an address (by parameter)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've got a function which, as is, works correctly. However the rest of the program has a limitation in that I've preset the size of the array (the space to be allocated). Obviously, this is problematic should an event arise in which I need extra space for that array. So I want to add dynamic allocation of memory into my program.

But I'm having an issue with the whole pointer to a pointer concept, and I've utterly failed to find an online explanation that makes sense to me...
I think I'll want to use malloc(iRead + 1) to get an array of the right size, but I'm not sure what that should be assigned to... *array? **array? I'm not at all sure.

And I'm also not clear on my while loops. &array[iRead] will no longer work, and I'm not sure how to get a hold of the elements in the array when there's a pointer to a pointer involved.

Can anyone point (heh pointer pun) me in the right direction?

Comment: if you have a pointer to pointer, then what's `array` in your original code will be `*array` in the new code. So, `*array = malloc(...)` and `sscanf(str, &(*array)[iRead])`. (alternatively, you can use `array[0]` for nicer-looking code, as in `array[0] = malloc()` and s`scanf(str, &array[0][Rread])`.)

Comment: You could parse the data twice. First time to establish its size without storing it, then allocate the memory, and re-read it into the array.

Comment: The "pointer to pointer concept" is simpler than you think. `void*` not withstanding, pointers are typed. The "what" which they point to is determined by that type. Just as `int* p;` declares a pointer to an `int`, an `int **pp;` denotes a pointer to an `int *`. Just as `*p = 5;` stores `5` at the address in `p`, `*pp = malloc(...);` stores the returned address from `malloc` invoke at the pointer address held in `pp`. Don't make it more complicated than that. And definitely jam up your compiler warnings to assist you in catching places where you accidentally use incorrect pointer types/vars.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I was definitely over complicating things in my mind. All those diagrams of boxes and arrows and whatnot made my brain explode just a tad. Thank for the pointers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of the following approaches.

1. First approach

   1. Make two passes through the file.
   2. In the first pass, read the numbers and discard them but keep counting the number of items.
   3. Allocate memory once for all the items.
   4. Rewind the file and make a second pass through it. In the second pass, read and store the numbers.

      ```
      int getNumberOfItems(FILE* fp, int hexi)
      {
         int numItems = 0;
         int number;

         char const* format = (hexi == 0) ? "%X" : "%d";
         while (fscanf(fp, format, &number) > 0) {
            ++numItems;
         return numItems;
      }

      void read(int *array, FILE* fp, int numItems, int hexi)
      {
         int i = 0;
         char const* format = (hexi == 0) ? "%X" : "%d";
         for ( i = 0; i < numItems; ++i )
            fscanf(fp, format, &array[i]);
      }

      int main(int argc, char** argv)
      {
         int hexi = 0;
         FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

         // if ( fp == NULL )
         // Add error checking code

         // Get the number of items in the file.
         int numItems = getNumberOfItems(fp, hexi);

         // Allocate memory for the items.
         int* array = malloc(sizeof(int)*numItems);

         // Rewind the file before reading the data
         frewind(fp);

         // Read the data.
         read(array, fp, numItems, hexi);

         // Use the data
         // ...
         // ...

         // Dealloate memory
         free(array);
      }
      ```
2. Second approach.

   1. Keep reading numbers from the file.
   2. Every time you read a number, use `realloc` to allocate space the additional item.
   3. Store the in the reallocated memory.

      ```
      int read(int **array, char* fpin, int hexi)
      {
         int number;
         int iRead = 0;

         // Local variable for ease of use.
         int* arr = NULL;
         char const* format = (hexi == 0) ? "%X" : "%d";

         FILE *fp = fopen(fpin, "r");
         if (NULL == fp){
            printf("File open error!\n");
            exit(-1);
         }

         while (fscanf(fp, format, &number) > 0) {
            arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(int)*(iRead+1));
            arr[iRead] = number;
            iRead += 1;
         }

         fclose(fp);

         // Return the array in the output argument.
         *array = arr;

         return iRead;
      }

      int main(int argc, char** argv)
      {
         int hexi = 0;
         int* array = NULL;

         // Read the data.
         int numItems = read(&array, argv[1], hexi);

         // Use the data
         // ...
         // ...

         // Dealloate memory
         free(array);
      }
      ```

Comment: I went with your second approach, which fit perfectly in with the program and worked wonderfully. They only change that needed to be made was to make the realloc line read:  arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(int) + iRead)).    Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
int read(int **array, char* fpin, int hexi) {
   int iRead = 0;
   int i, *ary;
   char *para;
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen(fpin, "r");
   if (NULL == fp){
      printf("File open error!\n");
      exit(-1);
   }

   para = (hexi == 0) ? "%*X" : "%*d";
   while (fscanf(fp, para)!= EOF)
     ++iRead;

   ary = *array = malloc(iRead*sizeof(int));
   if(ary == NULL){
      printf("malloc error!\n");
      exit(-2);
   }
   rewind(fp);
   para = (hexi == 0) ? "%X" : "%d";
   for(i = 0; i < iRead; ++i)
      fscanf(fp, para, &ary[i]);

   fclose(fp);
   return iRead;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a nice complete code.  Recommend `fscanf(fp, para) == 1` to avoid an infinite loop with incorrect data like "WXYZ".

Comment: @chux goot point. but `fscanf(fp, para) == 0` because for skip.

Comment: If you use the `%n` it is possible to determine whether the reading has been done. or `fscanf(fp, para, &temp) == 1`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
int read(int **array_pp, char* fpin, int hexi) {
  ...
  int *array = malloc (sizeof (int) * n);
  for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    fscanf(fp, "%X",&array[i]);
  ...
  *array_pp = array;
  return n;
}
```

Notes:

1) You must use "**" if you want to return a pointer in a function argument

2) If you prefer, however, you can declare two pointer variables (array_pp and array) to simplify your code.

Comment: This is currently wrong. This should be `fscanf(fp, "%X", &array[i]);` or `fscanf(fp, "%X", array+i);`. Either works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wouldn't call it an array. Arrays are of fixed size and lie on the stack. What you need (as you already said), is dynamically allocated memory on the heap.

maybe that's why you didn't find much :)
here are some tutorials:

- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Arrays (and following pages)
- http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html

you got the function declaration correctly:

```
int read(int **array, char* fpin, int hexi)
```

What you need to do:

1. find out how much memory you need, eg. how many elements
2. allocate it with `*array = malloc(numElements * sizeof(int))` (read "at the address pointed by array allocate memory for numElements ints")
3. now you can `(*array)[idx] = some int` (read "at the address pointed by array, take the element with index idx and assign some int to it")
4. call it with `int* destination; int size = read(&destination, "asdf", hexi)`

hope it helps..